# How to prevent swipe in HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know how it's possible to prevent swipe in HorizontalPager, and how I can load next element by lazy. Now HorizontalPager creates first and second elements at once.

Comment: Please don't ask two question at once. Using your question title it's impossible for others to find this question if they have the same problem. For the first one, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502096/how-to-disable-and-enable-scrolling-in-lazycolumn-lazyrow-in-jetpack-compose). Both answer methods are not perfect, but one of them most probably will suit you. As to your second question, I don't think it's possible. Consider creating your own wrapper of `LazyRow` and settings width to full available size using `Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()`

Answer (score 2):

in `HorizontalPager` method, use `userScrollEnabled = false` to prevent swipe