# How to create a Card with a lazy vertical list of items that can be nested within a scrollable Column using Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-column

I'd like to have a Compose UI that is something like this (overly-simplified version)...

[image]

Each carded list below each group is variable length depending on the list of items fed to the composable. Here's two options for how to approach this (using either a `Column` or `LazyColumn`):

```
@Composable
fun CardedColumn(items: ImmutableList<String>) {
    Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight().padding(8.dp)) {
        Column {
            items.forEach { text: String ->
                Text(text = text, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
                Divider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CardedLazyColumn(items: ImmutableList<String>) {
    Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight().padding(8.dp).animateContentSize()) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(items = items, key = { it }) { text: String ->
                Text(text = text, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).animateItemPlacement())
                Divider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
            }
        }
    }
}

//================================================================================
// Previews
//================================================================================
@Preview(widthDp = 320, heightDp = 320)
@Composable
fun CardedLazyColumn_Preview() {
    Column {
        val showItems = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Show items: ")
            Switch(checked = showItems.value, onCheckedChange = { showItems.value = it })
        }
        CardedLazyColumn(getItems(showItems.value))
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 320, heightDp = 320)
@Composable
fun CardedColumn_Preview() {
    Column {
        val showItems = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Show items: ")
            Switch(checked = showItems.value, onCheckedChange = { showItems.value = it })
        }
        CardedColumn(getItems(showItems.value))
    }
}

//================================================================================
// Helper Functions
//================================================================================
/**
 * Helper function to get more or less items depending upon [showMoreItems] argument
 */
private fun getItems(showMoreItems: Boolean): ImmutableList<String> {
    return if(showMoreItems) {
        persistentListOf("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet")
    } else {
        persistentListOf("Lorem", "dolor", "sit", "amet")
    }
}
```

If you try both Previews out in either **Interactive Mode** or in **Run Preview**, you'll notice that `CardedLazyColumn` animates the show/hide of new items while `CardedColumn` does not. This is due to the use of the `item` `key` in combination with `animateContentItemPlacement`, which bakes in the animation. This is why I would prefer to use a `LazyColumn`.

[image] [image]

Therefore, I'd like to create a screen akin to the following...

[image]

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Scaffold(topBar = { T23TopAppBar() }) { paddingValues: PaddingValues ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .fillMaxSize()
                //I want the full screen to be scrollable in case the content is too large
//                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
            val showItems = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text("Show items: ")
                Switch(checked = showItems.value, onCheckedChange = { showItems.value = it })
            }
            Text(
                text = "GROUP 1",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.overline,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            )
            CardedLazyColumn(getItems(showItems.value))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Text(
                text = "GROUP 2",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.overline,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            )
            CardedLazyColumn(persistentListOf("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Text(
                text = "GROUP 3",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.overline,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            )
            CardedLazyColumn(persistentListOf("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"))
        }
    }
}
```

But since there may be more items than fit on screen, I'd like the entire screen to be a scrollable Column to handle if there were more items than fit on screen. But as soon as I add `.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`, Compose throws an `IllegalStateException` ("IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed...").

I understand that ["nesting components scrollable in the same direction"](https://youtu.be/1ANt65eoNhQ?t=900) is a big ["no no"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271130/jetpack-compose-nested-lazycolumn-lazyrow). But, I don't even want my `LazyColumn`s to be scrollable. I simply want to have a ***variable length*** list that bakes in `items` + `animation` capabilities that are not included with a regular `Column`. And simply [setting the `LazyColumn`'s `userScrollEnabled` to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328009/1229936) doesn't prevent the `IllegalStateException` from being thrown.

**Now, my questions are:**

1. Is there some type of workaround to get this Carded `LazyColumn` to work inside a scrollable Column?
2. If not, is there a feasible way to at least replicate this type of behavior? (For example, using a `Column` but with animations somehow baked in)
3. Does it make more sense to just use the regular Carded `Column` and not include animations?

Replacing the outer scrollable `Column` with a `LazyColumn` and somehow flattening the `items` in each card to be `items` of the `LazyColumn` is the only thing I can think of. But that seems overly-complicated. For example, first item in the card would need to be a card with rounded top corners but cropped flat at the bottom. Last item in the card would need the opposite, etc.